# date conversion issue in java

Tags: java, hibernate, date, converters, date-conversion

I accept the user input date in yyyy/mm/dd format. When I try to convert using SimpleDateFormat it shows "null";

my code for conversion is:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateofbirthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd"); 
java.util.Date dateOfBirth = dateofbirthFormat.parse(birthdate);
```

why is it showing null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MM not mm,
MM is for months,
mm is for minutes

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateofbirthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
    try {
        java.util.Date dateOfBirth = dateofbirthFormat.parse("1986/12/11");
        System.out.println(dateOfBirth);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }
```

Comment: you're welcome :). you are supposed to mark the answer as correct. Users will find it useful.

Comment: Thanks Alexi. I am new here!! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

By    `yyyy/mm/dd`    I guest you mean years/Months/days. So you may try using
`yyyy/MM/dd`    (note upcase use of MM).

`SimpleDateFormat dateofbirthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
java.util.Date dateOfBirth = dateofbirthFormat.parse(birthdate);    .`